# angular template directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this route in angular

```
     when('/customers', {
        //templateUrl: 'customers.html'
        controller: 'ListController'
        , template: "<h1>{{customers}}</h1>"
    })
```

this works and it displays properly.i decide to go a bit bigger

```
   when('/customers', {
        //templateUrl: 'customers.html'
        controller: 'ListController'
        , template: "<div class=\"navigation-section\" id=\"customers\">\r\n    <div class=\"section\">\r\n        <div class=\"text-input-container card\"> <i class=\"icon-search text-input-icon\"><\/i>\r\n            <input type=\"text\" class=\"text-input  \" placeholder=\"Search\" ng-model=\"query1\" \/> <\/div>\r\n        <div> <\/div>\r\n    <\/div>\r\n    <div class=\"section\">\r\n        <ul class=\"list\">\r\n            <li ng-repeat=\"customer in customers | filter:query1 | orderBy:[\'customer.information.name\',\'customer.information.phone\']\" ripple>\r\n                <a href=\"#\/customer\/{{customers.indexOf(customer)}}\"><\/a>\r\n                <button class=\"icon-button\"><i class=\"icon-account-circle\"><\/i><\/button> <span class=\"item-text\">\r\n\t\t\t{{customer.information.name}}\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"secondary-text\">\r\n\t\t\t\t{{customer.information.phone}}\r\n\t\t\t<\/span> <\/span> <i class=\"icon-message item-action\"><\/i> <\/li>\r\n        <\/ul>\r\n    <\/div>\r\n<\/div>"
    })
```

this doesnt work why?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the template not load? Does the interpolation not work? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: Better yet, put it into a html file and use `templateUrl`, congrats, no need to escape all that html.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put the template in a file and load with templateUrl. However if you really, really need to implement it with raw template then you can use single quotes instead of double ones, so you do not have to escape the double quotes inside a template string, so sth like that:

```
...
template: '<div class="navigate-section"></div>',
...
```

You can also try and do sth like:

```
...
template: [
   '<div class="navigate-section">',
   '<span>Text</span>',
   '</div>'
].join('')
...
```

I think it should work and will increase readabilty a bit.

You can also add templates to cache as for example angular ui boostrap does it when you include single js file with templates, the tpls.js one.
It is sth like this:

```
angular.module('my/template/name.html', [])
  .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
     $templateCache.put(
        'my/template/name.html', '<div class="my-class"><span>Text</span></div>'
     );
}]);
```

You can also include in your main html file where your angular app runs the template as script with ng-template so you put

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template.html">
      <p>
        My template
      </p>
  </script>
```

and then, pass as templateUrl the string you put as id in script tag

```
...
templateUrl: '/template.html',
...
```

One of this methods, should resolve your issue. But still I would recomend loading templates for directives from files.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't expect all the escaped whitespace characters you have in your template. Try this version that's encapsulated in single quotes, has `\r\n\t`'s removed, and does not escape backslashes:

```
when('/customers', {
        //templateUrl: 'customers.html'
        controller: 'ListController', 
        template: '<div class="navigation-section" id="customers"><div class="section"><div class="text-input-container card"> <i class="icon-search text-input-icon"></i><input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query1" /> </div><div> </div></div><div class="section"><ul class="list"><li ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:query1 | orderBy:[\'customer.information.name\',\'customer.information.phone\']" ripple><a href="#/customer/{{customers.indexOf(customer)}}"></a><button class="icon-button"><i class="icon-account-circle"></i></button> <span class="item-text">{{customer.information.name}}<span class="secondary-text">{{customer.information.phone}}</span> </span> <i class="icon-message item-action"></i></li></ul></div></div>'
    })
```

Comment: You should also take a look at the many ways to plug into angular's `$templateCache` service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

As others suggested, this will help with template readability and future editing